# Dose Ruby OpenSSL::Cipher.reset clear key and iv as well?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl

The [document](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-reset) says that Cipher.reset fully resets the internal state of the Cipher.

I understand the document as Cipher.reset resets key, iv, and other state of Cipher.

To confirm it, I tried the code below.

```
require 'openssl'

enc = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC').encrypt
key = enc.random_key  
iv  = enc.random_iv

enc.reset res = "" 
res << enc.update('abc')  
res << enc.final 

p res
```

If Cipher.reset resets key and iv, encrypted string(res) must be the same every time the script runs.
But I get different result every time.

So I guess Cipher.reset does not reset key and iv.
Is it right?
And what does Cipher.reset do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran in to the same question as you, and I've devised the following test:

```
# encrypt data1 with random key and iv    
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.random_key
iv = cipher.random_iv
data1 = cipher.update('a') + cipher.final

# reset cipher, and encrypt with same key as above, don't touch iv
cipher.reset
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
data2 = cipher.update('a') + cipher.final

# reset cipher, don't touch key or iv
cipher.reset
cipher.encrypt
data3 = cipher.update('a') + cipher.final

data1 == data2 && data2 == data3 # => true
```

So as you can see neither iv nor key are changed by reset, since `data1`, `data2` and `data3` are all equal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your investigation!!

From your test and my test, we can reach the conclusion that `Cipher.reset` doesn't rest `key` and `iv`.  

I learned a lot since this.  
Thanks!!